# Olympiad Combinatorics Advice.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, contest-math, book-recommendation

I have been trying to improve my combinatorics for Math Olympiad. I am already familiar with like mid - AIME level, ie. essentially I only know short answer combo, and I wanted to improve to like USA(J)MO level and stuff.

But the problem is that there is no good book for olympiad combo (as [pranav sriram's book](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h601134)
is too $pr0$ for me right now.)
And I know that a lot of people say that there is no theory required for Oly combo but I think that's completely false as one needs to know a lot of graph theory, group theory, ramsey theory and many more things I don't even know the name of.

So, I bought a college textbook, [How to count by Slomson](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/1420082604/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o08_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and I have started to read it.

But one problem I face with college books is that compared to Oly books, the problems are much much tamer and not instructive. What I mean is say if I read a topic from the book, after that when I start to do the exercises, the problems are not such that would cause me (or anyone for that matter) any problems, that is they are usually "textbook problems". So when I learn something, I am not sure how to apply it.

For example, I just read the cycle notation for permutations but I don't understand what/ where it is used.

So my question is, what should I do? Should I continue with this book, learn the basic theory like graph theory/ group theory and so on and then move onto more advanced books/questions, or try something else. Also, is solving this book going to even help me for Olympiads?

Thanks!

Comment: You need an easier book like *Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics* by Chen Chuan-Chong. Googling "combinatorics olympiad handouts" gives several resources. Googling "combinatorics olympiad book mse" returns more posts like yours.

Comment: Have you seen AoPS's [Intermediate Counting and Probability](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/item/intermediate-counting)? See if you can do the diagnostic problems under 'do you need this?' to check up on your progress so far.